# when compiling a typescript library, how to build only to es2016?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, angular-library

I just wanted to compile my library in es2016 and obtain only the bundles directory.
At tsconfig.lib.ts i wrote:

```
"target": "es2016",
```

But when compilling still appeard

```
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
Bundling to FESM5
Bundling to UMD
Minifying UMD bundle
Copying declaration files
Writing package metadata
```

and creates lots of .d.ts files and various directories: bundles, esm5, esm2015, fesm5, fesm2015
is any way to stop the creation of all those files? or are them necesary?

Answer (score 0):

In the tsconfig.json file try specifying target as 
target: "es2016"
or in your case since its a library specify the same in tsconfig.lib.json